# Symfony2 : accessing entity fields in Twig with an entity field type

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Here is my FormType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user', 'entity', array(
            'class'   => 'UserBundle:User',
            'expanded' => true,
            'property' => 'name',
        ));
}
```

Is there a way to access user's fields in the view (Twig) ?

I'd like to do something like this :

```
{% for u in form.user %}
    {{ form_widget(u) }}
    {{ form_label(u) }}
    {% if u.moneyLeft > 0 %}
    <span>{{ u.name }} : {{ u.moneyLeft }} €</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

... where *moneyLeft* and *name* are fields from User entity.

Comment: Here's a link to a Symfony issue at Github that has some nice code to get folks headed in the right direction: [Issue 3836](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3836#issuecomment-23145270)

Answer (score 31):

In Symfony 2.5 - you can accomplish this by accessing the data from each choice using the child's index value.

In the form builder - as you might expect:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // Generate form
    $builder
        ->add('child', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'MyBundle:Child',
            'label'         => 'Children',
            'property'      => 'any_property_for_label',
            'expanded'      => true,
            'multiple'      => true
        ));
}
```

In the Twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% for child in form.child %}
    {% set index = child.vars.value %}{# get array index #}
    {% set entity = form.child.vars.choices[index].data %}{# get entity object #}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(child) }}</td>{# render checkbox #}
        <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.otherProperty }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: I suggest using `{% set entity = projectForm.stages.vars.choices[loop.index - 1].data %}` instead of getting index from entity property value. This way you can avoid unknown array key error.

Comment: @NikDenisov the loop has also a `loop.index0` variable: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable so no need for -1

Answer (score 10):

As of today, you can do the following in the master branch (and upcoming 2.1):

```
{{ u.vars.data.name }}
```

`u` is the form view for the user, which contains a list of attached variables. The `data` variable contains the normalized data of the form, which usually is your object (unless you added a custom model transformer).

In earlier versions of Symfony, you can do:

```
{{ u.vars.value.name }}
```

The `value` variable contains the view data of the form, which is also your object (unless you added a custom model or view transformer).

If you are working on Symfony master or >=2.1, I recommend to access `data` instead of `value`.

Comment: For an entity form type I had to do this:

`{{ u.data.field }}`

when iterating through choices

Comment: How this got votes, I have no idea. It's just plain wrong. I posted a comment under the OP with a link to a solution.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher: you could notice that bernhard is the same person whom closed the issue that you've linked onto github so I'm sure that you can figure out, now, why this answer has 6 upvotes: I'm sure (as I would answer the same way) that this method is working

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this with using a `query_builder`?

Comment: answer by Aaron below helped my scenario.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: {{ form.vars.data.businessName }} in newer versions.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me in Symfony 3.1 for a radio widget:

```
{% set entity = form.parent.vars.choices[form.vars.name].data %}
```

Comment: Hello, how can I do the same but with a CollectionType field ? Impossible to access to collection data because the method is private...

Answer (score 5):

**Version 2.6.7**

Similar to what Aaron Geiser suggested, you can use [customised form widgets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template) to achieve this:

```
{# src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{%- block entity_widget -%}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {%- for n, child in form %}
        {{- form_widget(child, {
            'entity': form.vars.choices[n].data
        }) -}}
        {{- form_label(child) -}}
    {% endfor -%}
    </div>
{%- endblock %-}

{%- block radio_widget -%}
{# You now have access to entity #}
{%- endblock -%}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update of [Bernhard Schussek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11655538/1668200)  for **Symfony 2.8.4** (or even somewhat lower version):

```
{% for key,value in form.user %} {# key is the ID in the database table #}
    {{ form_widget(value, {'label':value.vars.label}) }}
    {{ form.user.vars.choices[key].data.moneyLeft }} {# this syntax is new #}
{% endfor %}
```