# accessing other properties in twig of an entity field type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to display an entity field type expanded and with multiple set to true. However, I want to display the other properties of the entity. This is similar to [Symfony2 : accessing entity fields in Twig with an entity field type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335104/symfony2-accessing-entity-fields-in-twig-with-an-entity-field-type) but that solution hasn't worked for me. I'm getting the error: Item "code" for "" does not exist.

How can I access the other properties of the entity (color in this case)?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$builder->add('colors', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'PrismPortalCommonBundle:Color',
            'property' => 'code',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
        ));
```

and in the twig template:

```
{% for color in form.colors %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ form_widget(color) }}</td>
  <td>{{ color.vars.data.code }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please check what {{dump(color.vars.data)}} returns

Comment: Dump entire `form.colors` please. It seems like you've got "empty" objects

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 2.5 - you can accomplish this by accessing the data from each choice using the child's index value.

In the form builder - as you might expect:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // Generate form
    $builder
        ->add('child', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'MyBundle:Child',
            'label'         => 'Children',
            'property'      => 'any_property_for_label',
            'expanded'      => true,
            'multiple'      => true
        ));
}
```

In the Twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% for child in form.child %}
    {% set index = child.vars.value %}{# get array index #}
    {% set entity = form.child.vars.choices[index].data %}{# get entity object #}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(child) }}</td>{# render checkbox #}
        <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.otherProperty }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```